# How to remove top sep line in chapter and empty pages?

Tags: spacing, chapters, koma-script

I am trying to remove the top sep line (I want the bottom still to be there) for chapter and empty pages only while using KOMA. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question and answer correctly then you have to add option

```
cleardoublepage=plain
```

and to remove `plainheadsepline` (if it is in your original code).

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
    plainfootsepline,
    cleardoublepage=plain% <- added
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer to my question:

i redefined the empty page style to plain:

```
%%% renew style of empty pages
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\newpage%
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

and added the plainfootsepline option to scrbook

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
headsepline,
footsepline,
plainfootsepline
]{scrbook}
```

Comment: How does this relate to "the top sep line" in your question?

Comment: Do not redefine `\cleardoublepage` with a KOMA-Script class. Use the KOMA-Script option `cleardoublepage=<page style>` to change the page style of such pages.